# Running BIND9 In chroot

Tags: ubuntu, bind, chroot

I am trying to running bind9, on a ubuntu box, in a chroot jail, as discussed in "Linux System Administration" (Adelstein & Lubanovic).  The command "sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 start" is generating errors in syslog:

```
Jun 27 13:39:48 doli named[12418]: starting BIND 9.5.1-P2 -u bind -t /var/lib/named
. . . 
Jun 27 13:39:48 doli named[12418]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Jun 27 13:39:48 doli named[12418]: none:0: open: /etc/bind/named.conf: permission denied
Jun 27 13:39:48 doli named[12418]: loading configuration: permission denied
Jun 27 13:39:48 doli named[12418]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Jun 27 13:39:48 doli kernel: [426157.438173] type=1503 audit(1246124388.753:33): operation="inode_permission" requested_mask="r::" denied_mask="r::" fsuid=105 name="/var/lib/named/etc/bind/named.conf" pid=12419 profile="/usr/sbin/named"
```

The server is configured as follows:

- /etc/bind is symlinked to
  /var/lib/named/etc/bind.
- Ownerships for /var/.../etc and
  everything in it are set to
  bind:bind.
- /etc/default/bind9 has OPTIONS="-u
  bind -t /var/lib/named" (but I note
  that /etc/init.d/bind9 has OPTIONS=""
  and a notation that seems to say
  leave that alone and reset the value
  in /etc/default/bind9).

The syslog suggests the problem is that the process owner for bind9 can't read the configuration file, but it starts as root and resets to bind, either of which I would think should be able to read the configuration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You say that the ownerships are all bind:bind, even within the chroot bind shouldn't be able to overwrite it's configfiles imo, so it's conf stuff should be owned by root:bind, permission 640, so the bind group/user only has read access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: oops, AppArmor, not SELinux...

Look at /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named

There's a section that looks like this:

```
/etc/bind/** r,
/var/lib/bind/** rw,
/var/lib/bind/ rw,
/var/cache/bind/** rw,
/var/cache/bind/ rw,
```

I suggest adding this afterwards (or possibly replacing it with this):

```
/var/lib/named/etc/bind/** r,
/var/lib/named/var/lib/bind/** rw,
/var/lib/named/var/lib/bind/ rw,
/var/lib/named/var/cache/bind/** rw,
/var/lib/named/var/cache/bind/ rw,
```

Comment: I don't know.  I don't even know what SELinux is, sorry.  I'm running Ubuntu 9.04, Server Edition.  I get nothing when I run 'sudo find -name "SELinux*".

Comment: Yeah, don't know that one either.

What am I looking for?  I see /etc/apparmor, but neither logprof.conf nor rc.apparmor.functions have a references to named or bind.  And all their references to /etc are for subdirectories other than the ones involved with this.

Comment: /etc/apparmor.d, not /etc/apparmor

Comment: The Ubuntu forum discussion of bind9 points to apparmor as a potential issue, and seems to have solutions.  I'll see if I can figure this out from those.

Thanks for the lead.

Comment: apparmor is defiantly the issue here looking at the logs you posted. Changing the profile and restarting apparmor should resolve this.

Comment: usr.bin.named needed a few more lines to keep bind from bumping into things:
  /var/lib/named/etc/bind/** r,
  /var/lib/named/var/lib/bind/** rw,
  /var/lib/named/var/lib/bind/ rw,
  /var/lib/named/var/cache/bind/** rw,
  /var/lib/named/var/cache/bind/ rw,
  /var/lib/named/dev/log w,
  /var/lib/named/dev/null rw,
  /var/lib/named/dev/random r,

With these, it started without logging errors; "rndc status" reported no errors.

Comment: This is also helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5828381&postcount=17